# How do I not add duplicate values in dataverse Table power automate add rows

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dataverse

I am attempting to add rows to a dataverse table, but skip rows where a particular ID column has an existing value. I've created an alternate key using that column but it doesn't appear to do anything. Just add more rows.

I would rather avoid a lookup on each record insertion as the data is basic but there are lots of records to add at once

Answer (score 0):

Alternate keys is the way to go.
You might need to wait for a bit after creating the key for it start working properly.

> When an alternate key is created it will initiate a system job to create indexes on the database tables to enforce unique constraints on the columns used by the alternate key. The alternate key will not be in effect until these indexes are created. Creating these indexes may take some time depending on the amount of data in the system.

Check more info on how to [track the status index creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/define-alternate-keys-reference-records#track-the-status-of-the-creation-of-the-alternate-key) (Microsoft Docs site)

Also check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWgprFTkq0Y) for step by step demo and details on alternate keys

### To find system jobs

1. Open you app
2. Launch **Advanced Find**
3. Pick `System Jobs` table in **Look for** dropdown
4. Select **System Job Type** column **Equals** operator and `EntityKey Index Creation` job type
5. Click **[Results]** button

Comment: Cannot track the status in the basic powerapps UI which is annoying, had to search for how to get to the legacy UI but still can't find the status. I attempted another run of the flow to add rows and there was all duplicates. hmmm

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to detailed video and instructions on how to find a system job